# How to output php file in plugin instead of get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In theme i use following function with get_template_part to otput content of php file cc-archive.php
But when i use same function in my plugin it dosent work. what i can use instead of get_template_part ? i copied  cc-archive.php in same folder too still dont work.

```
function my_couse_cards($atts) {
    ob_start();
    $cat = $atts['id'] ;
    get_template_part(
    'cc-archive',
    null,
    array(
        'catid' => $cat
    )
);
    return ob_get_clean();   
}
```

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is never helpful. [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) returns `false` on failure. Does it? If so, that’s because [`locate_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) returns a falsey value. See the source of the last for why it is returning that

Comment: Actually get_template_part is a theme function , it dosent work for plugins , i want to know what alternative function i can use in plugin.

Comment: Yes, get_template_part() does not work for plugin. So, generally plugins are rolling themselves such helper function. WooCommerce have wc_locate_template() for such requirement. You can take it as reference and roll it on your own. https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_locate_template

Comment: If you just want to mimic what that function does, you can just `require` the file